# Fonts in Support Library 26.0.0-beta2: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: android, fonts

I'm trying to use new feature, to directly add font into xml but without luck.

I setup my project for **26.0.0-beta2** support library, created `font` resource folder in `res` folder, copied some fonts to it and when tried to build it, I received ***Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.*** message.

This is the structure:

[image]

my apps' `build.gradle` is nothing special:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '26.0.0-beta2'
    constraintLayout = '1.0.2'
    playServicesVersion = '10.2.6'
    butterknifeVersion = '8.0.1'
    stethoVersion = '1.5.0'
    realmStethoVersion = '2.0.0'
    daggerVersion = '2.11'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my module's `build.gradle` is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
    })

    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"

    //ConstrainLayout
    compile "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$constraintLayout"

    //Dager2
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I read somewhere that it is just enough to temporarily move fonts to somewhere outside of the project, do rebuild and then move them back, but that doesn't work, I get that message again. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For using these new functionalities, you will have to update 
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:` to 3.0.0-alpha1 at least